# How big a file will read_csv handle? Works for 10 lines of excel, but not 100000 -- says file doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas

Can't read in a large Excel file using `read_csv` - python error that file doesn't exist.

Smaller versions of same excel file open easily.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("E:\rawdata_50K.csv")
print(data[0:5])
```

Top 20 lines of excel file load perfectly; the large version does not.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962187/6705467

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: @Tim: The problem is the file name, nothing to do with file size.

Answer (score 2):

#### Note the `r` in front of the path if using Windows `\`

`data = pd.read_csv(r"E:\rawdata_50K.csv")`

or

#### Note the direction of the `/` in the path, doesn't require `r`

`data = pd.read_csv("E:/rawdata_50K.csv")`

#### File paths with `pathlib`:

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path

drive_path = Path('E:/')
file_path = drive_path / 'rawdata_50K.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: To be clear, without the raw-string `r` prefix, the path was to `E:<CARRIAGERETURN>awdata_50K.csv`, which of course does not exist. This is why you *always* use raw strings for Windows paths (and regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much! The 2nd solution in Answer 5 of the 6GB answer worked well and fast....

## Trying suggested methods

import pandas as pd
Fileread = pd.read_csv("E:\dataraw.csv", chunksize=500) 
dfList = []
for df in Fileread:
    dfList.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfList,sort=False)

print(df[99950:100000])

and perhaps someone can explain why the same CSV file worked when named as dataraw but did NOT work if renamed rawdata...(????)